# How to do the authentication to run Power Bi Rest Api in an Azure Function (PowerShell)?

Tags: powershell, authentication, powerbi, azure-functions

I created an Azure function with the language PowerShell. I would like to use the Power Bi Rest Api. What is the best way to do the authentcation from an Azure function? Can I use for example managed identity or an Azure app registration?

I would like to run for example:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/dataflows
```

Comment: Use OAUTH2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow and https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Connecting-from-power-BI-to-rest-API-with-Oath2-authentication/m-p/2221523

Comment: These are hyperlinks are talking about queries in Power Bi to get data from a rest api. I would like to run a seperated PowerShell script to get data from Power Bi. I would like to run for example https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/dataflows

Comment: It would be a Invoke-WebRequest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: @jdweng I still dont understand what you mean? Can you share some code snipped, tutorial or blog post?

Comment: See examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to run a seperated PowerShell script to get data from Power Bi.

You can make use of **`Login-PowerBIServiceAccount`** to connect to Power Bi:

```
Login-PowerBIServiceAccount

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/dataflows' -Method GET
```

[image]

Or if you want to make use of managed identity or App registration, use the below PowerShell script:

> **Note** that:  **My Workspace** isn't supported when using service principal that is myorg and works for only -   Service principal only works with new workspaces. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#considerations-and-limitations)

Create an **Azure AD application** and grant application API permissions:

[image]

**Add the service principal as admin to the workspace:**

*Go to Power BI Portal -> Your Workspace -> Click on ... -> Manage access -> +Add people or groups -> Search for Service Principal with name -> Admin*

[image]

Enable **"Allow access for service principals to call Power BI APIs"** in the Power Bi Admin portal:

[image]

```
# Replace these values with your own
$tenantId = "TenantID"
$appId = "AppID"
$appSecret = "ClientSecret"

# Authenticate with Azure AD using the App Registration
$authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = $appId
    client_secret = $appSecret
    scope = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"
}
$authResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $authUrl -Method POST -Body $body
$accessToken = ($authResult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token

# Call the Power BI REST API to retrieve a list of dataflows
$Url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/WorkSpaceID/dataflows"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Method GET -Headers $headers
$data = ($Result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).value

# Output the list of dataflows
$data
```

[image]